# Javascript show prompt until input less than 2

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to make a the page prompt the user for an input. I want it to keep showing a prompt until the number entered is less than 2.

My code isn't doing this correctly. When I press okay on my alerts, it just closes. I want the prompt to re show if the number entered is below 2.

I need this code written in a function called readNumberOfEntries.

***My code at the moment is :***

```
<script>
"use strict";

main();

/* You may not change anything in the mainFuncion */
function main() {

    var messageToDisplay = "Enter 1 to check whether data is sorted\n";
    messageToDisplay += "Enter 2 to check whether data represents a palindrome";

    var option = Number(prompt(messageToDisplay));

    readNumberOfEntries(option);

    if (option === 1) {
        if (isSorted()) {
            alert("Data is sorted");
        } else {
            alert("Data is not sorted");
        }
    }

    else if (option === 2) {
        if (isPalindrome()) {
            alert("Data represents a palindrome");
        } else {
            alert("Data does not represent a palindrome");
        }
    }

    else {
        alert("Invalid option provided.");
    }

}

function readNumberOfEntries($value) {
    /* YOU MUST IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION */
    var smaller_than_two = false;

    if($value < 2) {
        smaller_than_two = true;
    } else {
        smaller_than_two = false;
        //alert('Error: Number must be greater than or equal to 2');
    }

    while(!smaller_than_two) {
        if($value < 2) {
            smaller_than_two = true;
        }
    }
}

function isSorted() {
    /* YOU MUST IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION */

}

function isPalindrome() {
    /* YOU MUST IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION */
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to have your `readNumberOfEntries` function return the `smaller_than_two` variable, then for you to pull out the while loop from `readNumberOfEntries` and use it instead in your main function, which will keep prompting until true.

```
function main() {

    while(!readNumberOfEntries(option)){
        // alerts, etc ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply call `main()` again in `else` to retrigger the prompt

```
else {
    alert("Invalid option provided.");
    main()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your code is working correctly, but it is not being called more than once. Your `main();` call will call the working logic once, however you need to re-call it if it meets your conditions. I would recommend recursively calling `main()`

```
function main() {

  var messageToDisplay = "Enter 1 to check whether data is sorted\n";
  messageToDisplay += "Enter 2 to check whether data represents a palindrome";

  var option = Number(prompt(messageToDisplay));

  readNumberOfEntries(option);

  if (option === 1) {
      if (isSorted()) {
          alert("Data is sorted");
      } else {
          alert("Data is not sorted");
      }
  }

  else if (option === 2) {
      if (isPalindrome()) {
          alert("Data represents a palindrome");
      } else {
          alert("Data does not represent a palindrome");
      }
  }

  else {
    alert("Invalid option provided.");
  }

  if(option <2){
    main();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just run a loop inside `readNumberOfEntries`

```
function readNumberOfEntries($value) {
   while(true) {
      if($value>2) {
         return $value;
      } else {
         $value = Number(prompt("Enter a value greater than 2"));
      }
   }
}
```

Then assign the value returned by `readNumberOfEntries` to the `option`

```
option = readNumberOfEntries(option);
```

Comment: Great answer but where do I put the `option = readNumberOfEntries(option);` ?

Comment: After this line `var option = Number(prompt(messageToDisplay));`